# Date and Time format with ParseExact using Powershell

Tags: powershell, parser-error

I have a single ligne column (Called : Next Due Diligence Date) in my sharepoint list where i have a date with "MM-YYYY" format. I want to parse it to "01/MM/YYYY"

For this, I tried the Code below :

```
    $dateString =$IM["Next Due Diligence Date"]
    $format ="01/MM/YYYY"
    $start = [datetime]::parseexact($dateString, $format, $null)
```

I have this Error : Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `$IM["Next Due Diligence Date"]` contains value in `"MM-YYYY"` format, you could do something like this:

```
$dateString =$IM["Next Due Diligence Date"]
$dateStringParts = $dateString.Split('-');
$start  = New-Object DateTime([Int32]::Parse($dateStringParts[1]), [Int32]::Parse($dateStringParts[0]), 1)
```

and after that you could format the date with this:

```
$start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```